# What's polymorphic deployment

Tags: object-oriented, polymorphism

On pages 136 and 137 in *The Clean Coder*, Robert C. Martin describes how chips could be independently deployed thanks to a vtable:

> The solution was pretty simple. Each chip had to be decoupled from all
>   the others. Each had to be turned into an independent compilation unit
>   that could be burned independently of all the others.
>
> So I measured the sizes of all the functions in the application and
>   wrote a simple program that fit them, like a jigsaw puzzle, into each
>   of the chips, leaving 100 bytes of space or so for expansion. At the
>   beginning of each chip I put a table of pointers to all the functions
>   on that chip. At boot-up these pointers were moved into RAM. All the
>   code in the system was changed so that functions were called only
>   through these RAM vectors and never directly.
>
> Yes, you got it. The chips were objects, with vtables. **All functions
>   were polymorphically deployed.** And, yes, this is how I learned some of
>   the principles of OOD, long before I knew what an object was.

I know the [three kinds of polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), but what is polymorphic deployment?

Comment: What is a *chip*?

Comment: Presumably an EPROM.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. The application in question was a 32K embedded program, stored on 32 1K EEPROMs.

Comment: The author _described_ what "polymorphically deployed" means. He invented the term on the spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just Robert Martin being a bit flowery in his writing. Prior to Martin's work, a simple change in the program meant replacing all 32 EEPROM chips. By using pointers to functions, each of the 32 chips became independent of one another. That's all it means.

Comment: In the beggining of page 16 he also mentions it. Great book, tbh

Answer (score 0):

He mainly uses this term when suggesting the use of polymorphism instead of switch’s like in here https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism